# Como obtener el valor de un array de objeto en java

Tags: java, array, json, objeto

tengo un problema con un array, no estoy sabiendo como obtener sus valores de los objetos que tiene.
El array es el siguiente:

```
[
    {
      "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
      "nro_cuota": "3",
      "saldo": "149000.00",
      "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-06-04"
    },
    {
      "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
      "nro_cuota": "4",
      "saldo": "149000.00",
      "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-07-04"
    },
    {
      "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
      "nro_cuota": "5",
      "saldo": "149000.00",
      "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-08-04"
    },
    {
      "nro_factura": "001-001-0117196",
      "nro_cuota": "6",
      "saldo": "149000.00",
      "fecha_vencimiento": "2022-09-04"
    }
  ]
```

Si me pudieran dar algun tip de como puedo obtener esos valores por java (nro_factura, nro_cuota, saldo, fecha_vencimiento) les agradeceria bastante.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Usa la libreria de org.json, es facil.

solo debes "parsear" el contenido, por ejemplo si lo tienes en un string puedes usar :

```java
String jsonString = "\"facturas\" : ["
  + "  { "
  + "   \"nro_factura\": \"001-001-0117196\", "
  + "    \"nro_cuota\": \"5\", "
  + "    \"saldo\": \"149000.00", "
  + "    \"fecha_vencimiento\": \"2022-08-04\" "
  + "  }, "
  + "  { "
  + "      \"nro_factura\": \"001-001-0117196", "
  + "    \"nro_cuota\": \"6\","
  + "    \"saldo\": \"149000.00\","
  + "    \"fecha_vencimiento\": \"2022-09-04\" "
  + "  }"
  + "]"
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
Double saldo = obj.getJSONArray("facturas").getJSONObject(0).getDouble("saldo");
```

recuerda si el json contiene {} es un objecto, si contiene [] es un arreglo, datos con " son strings y numeros son enteros o dobles.

tambien recuerda usar caracteres de escape en este caso " para poner " entre las cadenas de caracteres

Comment: Entiendo amigo, agradezco tu respuesta, te comento. Yo ese dato estoy recibiendo de esta manera:
`respuestaPOJO.datos.get(2).toString()` 
Y ese array que pase en la pregunta es el resultado, y trate de hacer lo que me recomendaste pero parece que al ser de esa forma no estaría pudiendo acceder.

Comment: puedes compartir un poco mas de codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas colegas como están, quería comentarles que pude solucionar el problema con JsonParser. Les dejo el código por si les sirva a algunos.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        String codigoRetorno = null;
        String descRetorno = null;
        JsonArray detalle = null;

        if (parser.parse(respuesta).isJsonArray()) {//si es un array entra aca

            JsonArray JsonPadre = (JsonArray) parser.parse(respuesta);

            int b = 0;
            for (JsonElement jsonElement : JsonPadre) {

                b++;
                if (b == 1) {

                    codigoRetorno = jsonElement.getAsString();
                }
                if (b == 2) {

                    descRetorno = jsonElement.getAsString();
                }
                if (b == 3) {

                    detalle = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
                }
            }
```

Obs. En el tercer IF es donde se encuentra los datos de "nro factura, nro cuota, saldo y fechavencimiento". como ven una ves que se guarda en esas 3 variables ya pueden usarlas a su manera.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda